# Which Enhanced senses are possible for (mystic)adepts

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

Besides the default senses that the adept can gain from enhanced senses there are additional mentioned that he can gain which are in essence the same as bioware / cyberware senses.

I'm not sure which senses those are though as when I read through the restrictions I didnt see any sense that would fullfill them in the cyberware / bioware section as those parts which are mentioned in restriction came up in everyone of them.

So my question here is WHICH senses of these are allowed? (or am I misinterpreting the rules and it is just that only those parts that fall under restriction are not active while the other parts of the appropriate sense are?)

Comment: i'd guess any sense an animal/paranimal could have without cyberwere would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The power is talking about **low-light vision**, **microscopic vision** and **thermal vision**.
The mentioned **Natural Sonar** can be found on 4ed's Augmentation book, but there is an *ultrasound* enviromental compensation that can be obtained with an ultrasound sonar, which probably works the same way (read the rules for motion sensors on pages 365 and 446).

Comment: Are there also smell abilities (like tracking by smell) possible ? or do only these vision based ones not fall under the restricted part?

Comment: I could be mistaken, but i dont remember any critter's special ability that works like Smell, just enhanced senses.
But the adept power allows you to increase all five senses.